# Alfresco - Categories Picker

Tags: categories, alfresco-share

I want to use the JavaScript Alfresco.ObjectPicker component in order to have category picker into the file:  dnd-upload.get.html.ftl

```
<div class="form-field inlineable">
  <label >Catégories:</label>                             
    <div class="object-finder inlineable" id="a_default_prop_cm_categories-cntrl">                                       
        <div class="current-values inlineable object-finder-items" id="b_default_prop_cm_categories-cntrl-currentValueDisplay"></div>                                        
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="prop_cm_categories" id="c_default_prop_cm_categories"/>
        <div class="show-picker inlineable" id="d_default_prop_cm_categories-cntrl-itemGroupActions"><span class="yui-button yui-push-button" id="yui-gen7"><span class="first-child"><button type="button" tabindex="0" id="yui-gen7-button" >Sélectionner</button></span></span></div>                                    
        <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
        (function(){
                    var picker = new Alfresco.ObjectFinder("a_default_prop_cm_categories-cntrl", "c_default_prop_cm_categories").setOptions(
                   {                                                          
                      field: "prop_cm_categories",
                      compactMode: true,
                      mandatory: false,
                      currentValue: "",                                                                                                              
                      selectActionLabel: "Sélectionner",
                      minSearchTermLength: 1,
                      maxSearchResults: 1000
                   }).setMessages(
                      {""}
                   );
                   picker.setOptions(
                   {
                      itemType: "cm:category",
                      multipleSelectMode: true,
                      parentNodeRef: "alfresco://category/root",
                      itemFamily: "category",
                      maintainAddedRemovedItems: false,
                      params: "",
                      createNewItemUri: "",
                      createNewItemIcon: ""
                   }); 
        })();
        //]]>
        </script>                                   
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have declared a JS dependency in the same file:  dnd-upload.get.html.ftl

```
<@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/components/object-finder/object-finder.js" group="objectfinder"/>
```

When I click on the button : "Sélectionner" , nothing happens and I have no console error neither.

Do you , Please, have any idea about how to make this Picker Working ?

Regards,
Sofia.

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: Hello, I m using alfresco 5.0.d